# Как добавить форму созданную в Qt Designer в свое приложение

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

Код из обучалки не работает.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from gui import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
 
 
class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
 
 
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()
 
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Выдаёт такую ошибку

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "E:...\SomeName.py", line 3, in 
> from gui import Ui_MainWindow  # импорт нашего сгенерированного файла
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Ui_MainWindow' from 'gui' (E:...\gui.py)

**gui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog: object) -> object:
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(355, 53)
        Dialog.setSizeGripEnabled(True)
        self.FirstR = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Dialog)
        self.FirstR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 71, 21))
        self.FirstR.setObjectName("FirstR")
        self.FinalR = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Dialog)
        self.FinalR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 30, 61, 21))
        self.FinalR.setObjectName("FinalR")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 0, 61, 31))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 71, 31))
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 0, 75, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 0, 151, 51))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        Dialog.setWhatsThis(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p>Calculate XP</p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Last round</p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_2.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">First round</p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Calculate"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Гриша Хохлова опубликуйте модуль `gui,py`

Comment: @S.Nick готово!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от **`соответствующего виджета`**, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Вы создали форму на основании виджета QDialog, в котором класс называется `Ui_Dialog`.

Я отметил необходимые изменения, которые вам надо сделать.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# --- from gui__ui import Ui_MainWindow
# +++ from gui__ui import Ui_Dialog
# --> vvvvvvvvv <-------> ^^^^^^^^^ <-------------------------------------------
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog: object) -> object:
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(355, 53)
        Dialog.setSizeGripEnabled(True)
        self.FirstR = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Dialog)
        self.FirstR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 71, 21))
        self.FirstR.setObjectName("FirstR")
        self.FinalR = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Dialog)
        self.FinalR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 30, 61, 21))
        self.FinalR.setObjectName("FinalR")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 0, 61, 31))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 71, 31))
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 0, 75, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 0, 151, 51))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        Dialog.setWhatsThis(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p>Calculate XP</p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Last round</p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_2.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">First round</p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Calculate"))

 
# class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
# ---------------------> ^^^^^^^ <-------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
#        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()                                        # !!! +++
        
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        # тут ваша логика
 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = MyWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

1. Зайдите в *Qt Designer*.
   Во всплывающем окне '**`Новая форма`**' выберите **`Main Window`** и
   нажмите '**`Создать`**'. Далее вы создаете нужную вам форму и
   сохраняете ее в файл **gui.ui**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Выполните: `python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x gui.ui -o gui.py`
3. Запускаете ваш **SomeName.py**

   ```
   import sys
   from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
   from gui import Ui_MainWindow


   class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
       def __init__(self):
           super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

           self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
           self.ui.setupUi(self)


   if __name__ == '__main__': 
       app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
       application = MyWindow()
       application.show()

       sys.exit(app.exec())
   ```

Comment: я правильно поняла, что код писать прям в файле gui.py?

Comment: Просто у меня примерно та же ошибка

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\...\SomeName.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gui import Ui_MainWindow  # импорт нашего сгенерированного файла
ImportError: cannot import name 'Ui_MainWindow' from 'gui' (E:\...\gui.py)

Comment: @ГришаХохлова я же вам все отметил и написал. В модуле `gui.py` НЕТ класса `Ui_MainWindow()`. Замените `from gui__ui import Ui_MainWindow` на `from gui__ui import Ui_Dialog` или зайдите в Qt Designer и создайте новую форму наследуясь от класса `QMainWindow` и сконвертируйте  новый `gui.py`, тогда в вашем `main.py` ничего менять не надо.

Comment: Я поменяла имя на MainWindow и вот ошибка
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\...\SomeName.py", line 15, in <module>
    application = mywindow()
  File "E:\Калькулятор экспы\Front end.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
  File "E:\...\gui.py", line 19, in setupUi
    MainWindow.setSizeGripEnabled(True)
AttributeError: 'mywindow' object has no attribute 'setSizeGripEnabled'

Comment: @ГришаХохлова Я добавил обновление в свой ответ. Выполните все по шагам как я описал для вас.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Извините, но я уже всё написала на встраиваньи файла .ui в перменную (win = uic.loadUi("gui.ui")), и всё работает, и как гласит одна мудрость - "Работает, не трогай". Так что не смогу проверить по крайней мере до обновы данного моего приложения, а оно будет не думаю что скоро

Comment: @ГришаХохлова мне жаль потраченного времени, до свидания.

Comment: Ну извините, но я проверю работу вашего совета

Comment: Спасибо, вами предложеный вариант работает